# mypy not detecting a basic type error

Tags: python, static-typing, mypy

With python 3.5.1. and a current installation of mypy using git,
mypy flags error 1 & 2, but it does not report 3

What am I doing wrong, or is this a bug, or is this a known problem?

```
import typing

def test_ordered_dict(od: typing.Dict[str,int]) -> typing.Dict[str,int]:
    return 1   #type error 1

a = test_ordered_dict(1)   #type error 2

def test_me():
    a = test_ordered_dict(1)  # type error 3 is not reported
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My understanding from the [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html) is that mypy will only check a thing (module, function, whatever) if it's indicated to it that it should check it (by importing typing at module level or by annotating a function).

So 1 is checked because it's in a function which is typed, 2 is checked as the import typing indicates that your module is typed and it's at module scope but 3 is in the scope of an untyped function so it's ignored.

Comment: You can use `--check-untyped-defs` to catch this error.

Comment: The link seems to be dead.