# Python linter in vscode with incomplete type checking (Expected... got...)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lint, mypy, python-typing

I use vscode and I found the Python linter(s) do not detect when a python function is invoked with a parameter of different type than it's signature defines.

In this case, the function expects a `typing.Type[Exception]` instead of `Exception`:

[image]

Pycharm detects this situation:

[image]

I think `mypy` does not detect this one because it uses the `typing` module (`mypy` detects type mismatch in builtin types).

- Is there a way to configure mypy to detect cases like this?
- Which is the linter pycharm uses? Does it exist in vscode?
- Is there another linter that could do the job?

Note: I followed the flag suggestion from this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757469/mypy-not-detecting-a-basic-type-error) (`--check-untyped-defs`) but it didn't work.

Comment: i haven't tried this with pylance, but kite detects it.

Comment: @samthegolden -In VS Code, Linting for checking python code specifications includes 'Pylint', 'mypy', 'pycodestyle (pep8)', etc. You could refer to this document and try different Linting: [Linting in Vs Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting)

Comment: I have tried different linters, but none works. And I mention `mypy` since I know `mypy` does type checking (that many linters don't)

Comment: Are you using Pylance? If so, is the _Type Checking Mode_ set to strict?

Comment: @KYDronePilot and @aSaffary thanks for letting me know about `pylance`, it really does the job!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After following the suggestions in the comment section, I was able to do this in vscode by:

1. Installing the `Pylance` [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) and
2. Setting the following params on the User Settings:

```json
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "strict",
```