# mypy doesn't catch a type error if the error is in main(). Why?

Tags: python, mypy

mypy will catch an incompatible type error in this case

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        pass

channel = MyClass(0.)
```

but not this case

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        pass

def main():
    channel = MyClass(0.)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Why?

I am running python3.7.9 in Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mypy not detecting a basic type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757469/mypy-not-detecting-a-basic-type-error)

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the `main` function is untyped and mypy does not check it. To fix that issue add typing like:

```py
def main() -> None:
```

or pass `--check-untyped-defs` argument to mypy.